# printf a list of strings

Tags: haskell, string-formatting, pointfree

I have the following code that is supposed to format a telephone number. (`printf` is from Text.Printf, `splitPlaces` is from Data.List.Split).

```
prettyPrint :: String -> String
prettyPrint phoneNumber = printf "(%s) %s-%s" part1 part2 part3
  where [part1, part2, part3] = splitPlaces [3, 3, 4] phoneNumber
```

What I'm looking for is an operator that allows the following way of writing the function:

```
prettyPrint = printf "(%s) %s-%s" <operator> splitPlaces [3, 3, 4]
```

Does such an operator exist? Can it exist at all?

Comment: If you only want this for a list of fixed length, then it's easy: define `(#) p [x, y, z] = p x y z` and then say `printf "(%s) %s-%s" # ["000","111","2345"]`

Comment: If it's of a fixed length, it would be good to use a tuple: `p # (x, y, z) = p x y z`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming this operator should pop off elements from a list and pass them to a function one by one, no, that can't exist. Not *really*. It certainly is not a good idea. For this to work properly, you need to decide at runtime how many parameters to pass the function, a complete circumvention of the type system and all its benefits. You could say, lists are exactly here to properly state "I don't know how many elements there will be. `printf` itself rather violates much of Haskell's philosophy. The reason for its typeclass hackery of a variadic signature is *not* so much to allow a *varying number* of arguments, but arguments *of different type*, which is not relevant in your case.

What is easily implemented though is taking a *fixed* number of elements from the lists. Again not really a great idea because it's necessarily a partial function... but here goes:

```
pop3 :: (a -> a -> a -> b) -> [a] -> b
pop3 f [x,y,z] = f x y z
```

allowing you to write

```
printf "(%s) %s-%s" `pop3` splitPlaces [3, 3, 4] phoneNumber
```

Actually, we can generalise this: still fixed number at compile-time, but with a single name for any such number:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances      #-}

class YieldsEventually f a b where
  popN :: f -> [a] -> b

instance YieldsEventually b a b where
  popN = const

instance (YieldsEventually f a b) => YieldsEventually (a->f) a b where
  popN f (x:xs) = popN (f x) xs
```

However, combining two functions that both require monomorphic arguments to resolve their own polymorphism-variadicity can't possibly work well, you need to fully qualify everything to make it compile:

```
(printf "(%s) %s-%s" :: String -> String -> String -> IO())
         `popN` (splitPlaces [3, 3, 4] phoneNumber :: [String])
```

*Not nice*.

I think your original approach is the best; the explicit pattern also allows you to insert proper failure handling.

---

Finally, and *obviously evilest*, here is the dynamic-numbers-of-arguments solution:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

popNPrintfr :: PrintfArg a => (forall p. PrintfType p => p) -> [a] -> IO ()
popNPrintfr printr [] = printr
popNPrintfr printr (x:xs) = popNPrintfr (printr x) xs
```

Again simpler to be used:

```
printf "(%s) %s-%s" `popNPrintfr` splitPlaces [3, 3, 4] phoneNumber
```

Comment: I believed to understand your answer until you added the generalization… Thanks!

Comment: You can generalize the type of `popNPrintfr` to `(PrintfType q, PrintfArg a) => (forall p. PrintfType p => p) -> [a] -> PrintfType q`

Comment: @kosmikus: you mean `... -> [a] -> q`. Yes, that would be possible; I figured it would cause type deduction problems like with `popN` but actually it seems to work fine.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Yes, sorry for the typo.